# How to Pass data from ajax to django views

Tags: html, json, ajax, forms, django-views

I have Json data like this:

[{"item":"Datalogger","hsn":"123","unit_name":"BAG","unit_price":"100","quantity":"6",
"tax_code":"GST 18","base_discount":"5","discount_value":30,"amount":570,"state":"Maharashtra",
"tax_no":"18","tax_name":"GST","base_Amount":600,"CGST":54,"SGST":54},
{"item":"Datalogger","hsn":"123","unit_name":"BAG","unit_price":"100","quantity":"6",
"tax_code":"GST 18","base_discount":"5","discount_value":30,"amount":570,"state":"Maharashtra",
"tax_no":"18","tax_name":"GST","base_Amount":600,"CGST":54,"SGST":54}]

I want to pass this data to django view by using ajax. my ajax code is

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:" {% url 'get-invoice-items'%}",
        headers:{
            "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}'
             },
        data: JSON.stringify(items),
        success: function(data) { console.log("data",data) },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(response){
        console.log(response)
    })
    .fail(function(response){
        console.log(response)
    })
    ;
```

and in django views I am doing this

```
def get_invoice_items(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        data = request.POST.get('data', None)
        print(data)
       
    # return HTTPResponse(data)
    return JsonResponse({"message" : "Request Handled.."})
```

I wish to print data in my django view. what I need to do here???

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.get_json()` to get the data

```
data = request.get_json()
```